# Apache FOP For PDF Overprinting

Tags: apache-fop

I have the following scenario:

I have a PDF document with no form fields. However, the PDF document is something of a form letter, with various sections that need to be "overprinted" at exact points.

Can this be done with FOP and a custom XSLT stylesheet?

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific requirement to use `Apache FOP`? I evaluated both `FOP` and `apache PDFBox` and found `PDFBox` to be better suitable even for your requirement.

Following are some of the useful links for PDFBox:

UserGuide: http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/index.html

Tutorial on some functionalities: http://www.printmyfolders.com/Home/PDFBox-Tutorial

Comment: Actually, that would be a good answer. We have some forms as PDF fillable, some that need to be overprintted, etc. I was already looking at PDFBox to fill the forms out.

Comment: Yeah i have accomplished this using pdfbox